# Paypal express checkout : Capture the amount in paypal site, not in your site

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I am using Paypal express checkout with Authorized and Capture facility in my site which is built in CI. I can authorize and capture from my site. My requirement is little bit different. I will capture that amount in Paypal site not in my site. Is that possible? If yes how and where can I do this? Is there anyway to update database after capturing?

Comment: Is there anybody to help me out from this issue

Answer (score 1):

You can capture authorizations from your account transaction history. Have a look at [Using Authorization & Capture](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/authcapture/) and scroll down to the section titled "Basic Authorization & Capture Scenarios". This covers capturing a single or multiple authorizations.

Comment: I am using sandbox. When I click on 'History' tab it gives me error says. 'Sorry — your last action could not be completed'